# How do I print the index from this array after I've randomly picked a selection?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have an array of quotes stored in a json file called `quotes.json`. I read the file and am able to pick and output a random quote using the code below, but when I try to display the number of the quote, it shows up like `Quote [object Object] of 3`. What am I doing wrong?

```
[
    {"quote": "quote 1"},
    {"quote": "quote 2"},
    {"quote": "quote 3"}
]
```

```
let quote_num = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Quote")
    .setColor(0x27367A)
    .setFooter(`Listening for ${prefix}`, `${bot_avatar_url}`)
    .setThumbnail(`${bot_avatar_url}`)
    .setTimestamp()
    .addField(`Quote ${quote_num} of ${quotes.length}`, `'${quote_num.quote}'`)

message.channel.send({embed});
```

Comment: try logging you object like this `console.log(JSON.stringify(embed))`...

Comment: thanks, the bot displays my embed and th quote just fine. the only part that doesn't work is the display of ```${quote.num}```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's analyze this code

```js
let quote_num = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
```

Firstly you get random number from the range of your array

```js
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)
```

Then you get object from array of objects by index

```js
let quote_num = quotes[index]
```

So to get index of your object you have to edit your `addField` method in this way

```js
.addField(`Quote ${index} of ${quotes.length}`, `'${quote_num.quote}'`)
```

**Summary:**
Your `quote_num` contains resulted object but not it's index in array of objects.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it in such a detailed and straight forward manner. I'll try that.